# Does it make sense notation to say $L^{2}$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I was reading something and it says let $\| x\|_2$ be the $L^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is a minor point but does it actually make sense to call it $L^2$ norm here? I thought maybe $\ell^2$ norm maybe more appropriate? (maybe it does not matter at all?)
And this would be the same for $\ell^{\infty}$ and $L^{\infty}$ as well perhaps?

Comment: $\ell_p$, with subscript index, is pretty standard to describe the $p$-norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The superscript version $\ell^p$ is commonly dedicated to sequence spaces.

Comment: Ok, thank u and same with when $p$ is infinity as well?

Comment: Yes, it is the same notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\mathbb{R^n}$ with the $p$-norm is a special $L^p$ space with the counting measure on $\{1,...,n\}$: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have that
$$\int |x|^p \mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n |x(i)|^p$$
Because we can identify every element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a function from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, as in yes it makes sense to use $L^2$ notation?

Comment: @JognnyT. It makes sense as an $L^2$ space. Similarly, $l^p$ is also a special case of $L^p$ (also with the counting measure).

Comment: Possibly "with the counting measure" might be better written "with the counting measure on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$"...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right. I omitted it, because all of the functions are $\{1,...,n\} \to \mathbb{R}$.